# boost::variant - get vector property of members

Tags: c++, boost, apply, visitor-pattern

I am stuck :). I have two-level hierarchy, each level has child nodes.
The goal is to use this structure to populate gui tree. I am trying to access child nodes of variant members in a generic manner. Following code does not compile, using vs2013. I'll appreciate the helping hand and/or advise
on the design changes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class base {};

class A : public base
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>> & lst(){ return _lst; }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>> _lst;
};

class B : public base
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& lst() { return _lst; }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> _lst;
};

using bstvar = boost::variant<A, B>;

class lstVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    template <typename T> std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>>& operator()  (T& t) const
    {
        return t.lst();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bstvar test;
    auto& lst= boost::apply_visitor(lstVisitor{}, test);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your visitor has an implicit return type of `void` (the template argument is missing).

Here's taking the opportunity to remove the base class as it's no longer needed in most c++11 code bases:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d855e12782bb5391)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class base {};

using base_vec = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base> >;

class A : public base {
  public:
    base_vec &lst() { return _lst; }

  private:
    base_vec _lst;
};

class B : public base {
  public:
    base_vec &lst() { return _lst; }

  private:
    base_vec _lst;
};

using bstvar = boost::variant<A, B>;

struct lstVisitor {
    using result_type = base_vec&;
    template <typename T> result_type operator()(T &t) const { return t.lst(); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bstvar test { B{} };
    base_vec& lst = boost::apply_visitor(lstVisitor{}, test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Question pertaining to your comment:you changed the return paramenter of lst() to std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base> >
Class B in the example has this list return vectors of shared pointers to A.
I don't see how can I determine the type of the elements in the container if
it returns pointer to the base class.

Comment: Huh. `operator()` clearly already returns that. If you insist, you can only convert and return a copy...: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2611392cee514d8e). By now I think you need to make up your mind: what do you need static polymorphism for, and why do you want dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: The latter has nothing to do with variant: see [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) and [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast). Also, if you need different return types, that means you cannot have a single visitor. You can of course return... another variant (uhoh): **[like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e87a1b585a59fab)** but that seems like a reasonably large [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me.

Comment: I am trying to create a tree structure to replace my Qt code for treeview.<br />