# How to generalize a tree structure with variant/visitor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

This is a part 2 of my question, originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166181/boostvariant-get-vector-property-of-members). Thanks to @sehe for clarifications and help. I ended up with the code that follows, but I can't figure out how can I reduce this thing to a generic solution with variant and visitor. Help/advise is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>


template <typename T> class A 
{
public:
    typename T L;
    typename std::shared_ptr<T> Lptr;
    using tlist = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>;
    A(std::string n = "") : _n(n){}
    A(const A& another) : _n(another._n){};
    A(A&& a) : _n(a._n){ _lst = std::move(another._lst); }
    tlist &lst() { return _lst; }
    void emplace_back(std::shared_ptr<T> wp) {
        _lst.emplace_back(wp);
    }
    std::string n() const { return _n; }
private:
    tlist _lst;
    std::string _n;
};

/*
suppose I have following tree structure
    Store
        Shelves
            Products on the shelve
*/
using lA = A<boost::blank>; // product
using lB = A<lA>;           // shelf
using lC = A<lB>;           // store
using lAp = std::shared_ptr<lA>;
using lBp = std::shared_ptr<lB>;
using lCp = std::shared_ptr<lC>;


void printIt(lAp p, int indent){
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << '\t';
    std::cout << p->n() << std::endl;
}


void printIt(lBp p, int indent){
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << '\t';
    std::cout << p->n() << std::endl;;
    std::for_each(begin(p->lst()), end(p->lst()), [&](lAp i){
        printIt(i, indent + 1); }
    );
}


void printIt(lCp p, int indent){
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << '\t';
    std::cout << p->n() << std::endl;
    std::for_each ( begin(p->lst()), end(p->lst()), [&](lBp i)
    {
        printIt(i, indent + 1);
    });
}


int main() {
    using storage = boost::variant<lAp, lBp, lCp>;
    std::vector<lCp> stores;
    for (int s = 0; s < 5; ++s) {
        lCp store(new lC((boost::format("store %1%") % s).str()));
        stores.emplace_back(store);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {// ten shelves in the store
            lBp shelf(new lB((boost::format("shelf %1%") % i).str()));
            store->emplace_back(shelf);
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) // twenty producs per shelf
                shelf->emplace_back(std::shared_ptr<lA>(new lA((boost::format("product %1%") % j).str())));
        }
    }
    std::for_each(begin(stores), end(stores), [](lCp p){printIt(p,0); });
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. ### [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) first

   I'm not sure what the goal is with all the polymorphism, both static and dynamic. I'd say if your type structure is fixed like that, just use:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0b55f759e2bccc5)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>

   namespace SimpleDomain {

       struct Product {
           std::string name;
       };

       struct Shelf {
           std::string name;
           std::vector<Product> _products;
       };

       struct Store {
           std::string name;
           std::vector<Shelf> _shelves;
       };

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Product const& p) {
           return os << "\t\t" << p.name << "\n";
       }
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shelf const& s) {
           os << "\t" << s.name << "\n";
           for (auto& p : s._products) os << p;
           return os;
       }
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Store const& s) {
           os << s.name << "\n";
           for (auto& sh : s._shelves) os << sh;
           return os;
       }
   }

   int main() {
       std::vector<SimpleDomain::Store> stores = {
           { "store 1", {
                   { "shelf 1", { { "product 1" }, { "product 2" }, { "product 3" }, } },
                   { "shelf 2", { { "product 4" }, { "product 5" }, { "product 6" }, } },
                },
           },
           { "store 2", {
                   { "shelf 1", { { "product 7" }, { "product 8" }, { "product 9" }, } },
                   { "shelf 2", { { "product 10" }, { "product 11" }, { "product 12" }, } },
                },
           }
       };

       std::for_each(begin(stores), end(stores), 
               [](SimpleDomain::Store const& p){std::cout << p;});
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   store 1
       shelf 1
           product 1
           product 2
           product 3
       shelf 2
           product 4
           product 5
           product 6
   store 2
       shelf 1
           product 7
           product 8
           product 9
       shelf 2
           product 10
           product 11
           product 12
   ```
2. ### Full Genericity, No Dynamic Polymorphism:

   Here you could use a recursive variant to be more generic:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf8ca35654f53277)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>
   #include <boost/variant.hpp>

   namespace GenericDomain {

       namespace Tag {
           struct Store{};
           struct Shelf{};
           struct Product{};
       }

       template <typename Kind> struct Node;

       using Store   = Node<Tag::Store>;
       using Shelf   = Node<Tag::Shelf>;
       using Product = Node<Tag::Product>;

       using Tree = boost::variant<
           boost::recursive_wrapper<Product>,
           boost::recursive_wrapper<Store>,
           boost::recursive_wrapper<Shelf>
       >;

       template <typename Kind> struct Node {
           std::string name;
           std::vector<Tree> children;
       };

       template <> struct Node<Tag::Product> {
           std::string name;
       };

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Store)   { return os << "Store";   }
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Shelf)   { return os << "\tShelf";   }
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Product) { return os << "\t\tProduct"; }

       template <typename Kind> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node<Kind> const& n) {
           os << Kind{} << ": " << n.name << "\n";
           for (auto& child : n.children) os << child;
           return os;
       }
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Product const& p) {
           return os << Tag::Product{} << ": " << p.name << "\n";
       }
   }

   int main() {
       using namespace GenericDomain;
       std::vector<Store> stores = {
           Store { "store 1", {
                   Shelf { "shelf 1", { Product { "product 1" },  Product { "product 2" },  Product { "product 3" }, } },
                   Shelf { "shelf 2", { Product { "product 4" },  Product { "product 5" },  Product { "product 6" }, } },
                },
           },
           Store { "store 2", {
                   Shelf { "shelf 1", { Product { "product 7" },  Product { "product 8" },  Product { "product 9" }, } },
                   Shelf { "shelf 2", { Product { "product 10" }, Product { "product 11" }, Product { "product 12" }, } },
                },
           }
       };

       std::for_each(begin(stores), end(stores), 
               [](GenericDomain::Store const& p){std::cout << p;});
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   Store: store 1
       Shelf: shelf 1
           Product: product 1
           Product: product 2
           Product: product 3
       Shelf: shelf 2
           Product: product 4
           Product: product 5
           Product: product 6
   Store: store 2
       Shelf: shelf 1
           Product: product 7
           Product: product 8
           Product: product 9
       Shelf: shelf 2
           Product: product 10
           Product: product 11
           Product: product 12
   ```

   You can see that we can detect the type of node. Of course, nothing prevents us from making bizarre hierarchies:

   ```
   std::vector<Store> stores = {
       Store { "store 1", {
           Shelf { "shelf 1", { 
               Product { "product 1" },
               Store { "store 2", {
                   Shelf { "shelf 1", { Product { "product 7" },  Product { "product 8" },  Product { "product 9" }, } },
                   Shelf { "shelf 2", { Product { "product 10" }, Product { "product 11" }, Product { "product 12" }, } },
               }, },
               Product { "product 3" },
           } },
           Shelf { "shelf 2", { Product { "product 4" },  Product { "product 5" },  Product { "product 6" }, } },
       }, },
   };
   ```

   To generically handle the indentation, make a stateful visitor:

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Store)   { return os << "Store";   }
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Shelf)   { return os << "Shelf";   }
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Product) { return os << "Product"; }

   struct print_vis {
       size_t indent = 0;
       std::ostream& _os;

       using result_type = void;

       template <typename Kind> void operator()(Node<Kind> const& n) const {
           _os << std::string(indent, ' ') << Kind{} << ": " << n.name << "\n";
           print_vis sub { indent+4, _os };
           for (auto& child : n.children) sub(child);
       }

       void operator()(Product const& p) const {
           _os << std::string(indent, ' ') << Tag::Product{} << ": " << p.name << "\n";
       }

       void operator()(Tree const& tree) const {
           boost::apply_visitor(*this, tree);
       }
   ```

   Prints: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a41d039e3773d02)</kbd>**

   ```
   Store: store 1
       Shelf: shelf 1
           Product: product 1
           Store: store 2
               Shelf: shelf 1
                   Product: product 7
                   Product: product 8
                   Product: product 9
               Shelf: shelf 2
                   Product: product 10
                   Product: product 11
                   Product: product 12
           Product: product 3
       Shelf: shelf 2
           Product: product 4
           Product: product 5
           Product: product 6
   ```
3. ### No Variants, Dynamic Polymorphism Only

   With the same "weird" tree as just above with the GenericDomain tree:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0e33d9b1a6b3b03)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>
   #include <memory>

   namespace DynamicDomain {

       struct Node;
       using Tree = std::shared_ptr<Node>;

       struct Node {
           virtual std::string type() const = 0;
           std::string name;
           std::vector<Tree> children;

           template <typename... Child>
           Node(std::string name, Child&&... children) : 
               name(std::move(name)), children { std::forward<Child>(children)... }
           { }
       };

       struct Product : Node { using Node::Node; virtual std::string type() const { return "Product"; } };
       struct Shelf   : Node { using Node::Node; virtual std::string type() const { return "Shelf"; } };
       struct Store   : Node { using Node::Node; virtual std::string type() const { return "Store"; } };

       struct print_vis {
           size_t indent;
           std::ostream* _os;

           using result_type = void;

           void operator()(Tree const& tree) const {
               if (tree) (*this) (*tree); else *_os << "[null]";
           }
           void operator()(Node const& node) const {
               *_os << std::string(indent, ' ') << node.type() << ": " << node.name << "\n";
               print_vis sub { indent+4, _os };
               for (auto const& child : node.children) sub(child);
           }
       };

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tree const& n) {
           print_vis{0, &os} (n);
           return os;
       }
   }

   int main() {
       using namespace DynamicDomain;
       std::vector<Tree> stores = {
           std::make_shared<Store> ("store 1", 
                   std::make_shared<Shelf> ("shelf 1",
                           std::make_shared<Product> ("product 1"),
                           std::make_shared<Store> ("store 2",
                                   std::make_shared<Shelf> ("shelf 1",  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 7"),  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 8"),  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 9") ),
                                   std::make_shared<Shelf> ("shelf 2",  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 10"), std::make_shared<Product> ("product 11"), std::make_shared<Product> ("product 12") )
                                   ),
                           std::make_shared<Product> ("product 3")
                           ),
                   std::make_shared<Shelf> ("shelf 2",  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 4"),  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 5"),  std::make_shared<Product> ("product 6") )
                   ),
       };

       std::for_each(begin(stores), end(stores), 
               [](DynamicDomain::Tree const& p){ std::cout << p; });
   }
   ```

   Not my idea of "neat" and potentially much less efficient - although it does allow for nullable nodes and sharing of subtrees.

Comment: Added two variant-based examples.

Comment: Added the runtime polymorphic approach (i.e. with your shared_ptr and virtual methods instead of variant and argument type overloading). Hope you can see the various approaches you were mixing. I strongly believe you wanted the ["KISS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) option

Comment: I have adopted your GenericDomain approach. Question:  How to use structures defined in Tag namespace for resolving tag-specific values in visitor? 
I ended up modifying 
template <typename Kind> struct Node
to include "kind", like this:
 template <typename Kind> struct Node 
 {
..  Kind kind;
 };

so I can use "kind" for iterations with typeid

 struct vstType: public boost::static_visitor<int>
 {
  template<typename T> int operator()(T& p) const {
   if ((typeid(p.kind) == typeid(Tag::Store)))
    return 1;
   return 2;
  }
 };

 Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've ever seen on SO.