# Flexible hierarchy with boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, variant

The question is a modified code provided by @sehe [as part of his answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197445/how-to-generalize-a-tree-structure-with-variant-visitor). This modification include the parent of each node. Sample structure is Store->Shelves->Products. I want to have parent in each node. The code compiles just fine, but the "parent" member of the node is apparently destroyed. I'll appreciate the help in figuring out why. Thanks!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <boost/variant.hpp>
    #include <boost/format.hpp>

    namespace GenericDomain {

        namespace Tag {
            struct Store{};
            struct Shelf{};
            struct Product{};
        }

        template <typename Kind> struct Node;

        using Store = Node<Tag::Store>;
        using Shelf = Node<Tag::Shelf>;
        using Product = Node<Tag::Product>;

        using Tree = boost::variant<
            boost::recursive_wrapper<Product>,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<Store>,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<Shelf>
        >;

        template <typename Kind> struct Node {
            std::string name;
            std::vector<Tree> children;
            Kind kind;
            Tree* parent;
            Node(std::string ofname, Tree* ofparent) : name(ofname), parent(ofparent) {}
        };

        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Store)   { return os << "Store"; }
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Shelf)   { return os << "\tShelf"; }
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tag::Product) { return os << "\t\tProduct"; }

        struct vstName : public boost::static_visitor<const std::string&>
        {
            template<typename T> const std::string& operator()(T& p) const {
                return p.name;
            }
        };

        template <typename Kind> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node<Kind> const& n) {
            os << Kind{} << ": " << n.name << "\n";
            if (n.parent == nullptr)
                os << "root\n";
            else {
                vstName visitorName;
                std::string parentname = boost::apply_visitor(visitorName, *n.parent);
                os << "parent of " << parentname << "\n";
            }
            for (auto& child : n.children) os << child;
            return os;
        }

        std::string test1()
        {
            std::vector<Tree> stores;
            for (int s = 0; s < 2; ++s)
            {
                stores.emplace_back(Tree(Store((boost::format("store %1%") % s).str(), nullptr)));
                Tree& store = *stores.rbegin();
                std::vector<Tree>& shelves = boost::get<Store>(store).children;
                for (int sh = 0; sh < 2; ++sh) {
                    shelves.push_back(Tree(Shelf((boost::format("shelf %1%-%2%") % s %sh).str(), &store)));
                    Tree& shelf = *shelves.rbegin();
                    std::vector<Tree>& products = boost::get<Shelf>(shelf).children;
                    for (int pr = 0; pr< 2; ++pr) 
                        products.push_back(Tree(Product((boost::format("product %1%-%2%-%3%") % s %sh %pr).str(), &shelf)));
                }
            }

            std::ostringstream oss;
            std::for_each(begin(stores), end(stores),
                [&](const Tree& p){oss << p; });
            return oss.str();
        }

    };
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << GenericDomain::test1();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and link to the previous answer; also please post a [MCVE]

Comment: question is updated with the link to prev.question and added main function to complete code sample.

Comment: which errors do you get? what is your expected output?

Comment: when code runs it blows up at the line std::string parentname = boost::apply_visitor(visitorName, *n.parent); looks like n.parent is deallocated. I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: changing the line 
std::vector<Tree> stores;
to
std::vector<Tree*> stores;
and having vector of pointers in Node made it to work. But the academic interest remains - why it does not work for std::vector<Tree>

Comment: What do you mean it "looks like" it's deallocated? You determine this by adding debugging output to the ctors / dtors? Did you also check the move ctors? There's a good chance spirit is moving it I think. When you ask an SO question like this, you should put ALL such debugging output into the text in your question, then post your question in the form, "Why do I see this output?" <paste output> Such questions are very sensitive to exactly how you tested, and many posters overlook simple things.